# A customer, customers or customer

Tags: grammatical-number, articles

Can anyone explain to me when to use 'a customer', 'customers' or 'customer'?

For example, which of the following is the most appropriate?

1. If customers have a problem, as a customer representative, I will always offer my help.
2. If customer has a problem... (the same as above)
3. If a customer has a problem...(the same as above)
4. If customers have problems... (the same as above)

Comment: (2) is over-terse. The others are acceptable, (1) looking perhaps unbalanced but patterned after 'if people have a headache', but (3) seems most idiomatic, identifying a single example. 'I will always ...' is a paraphrase for 'whenever this might occur'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouns in singular always need an article: A customer, a problem (if both are unknown at the time of speaking). Most likely (I hope) each customer will have a single problem, so I would use "If *a*  customer has *a* problem  ..."

The double plural "If customers have problems" is grammatically correct. But it seems to address the customers as a collective, whith a multitude of problems. In the position of a customer representative, I understand, you would handle a limited number of customers, one by one, so the singular seems more appropriate to me.

By contrast, a marketing person might address the collective: "If our customers do not like the new design, we can quickly revert to the old one." Or the product manager might say "That our customers have so many problems is a direct result of our understaffed test department."

Comment: Great answer. I encountered this sentence on an exercise pdf and I think it's grammaticaly wrong, what do you think? ' I also wanted to find out what they know about our competition and if the location of the customer made any difference in how long they’ve been our customer. '

Comment: Doesn't seem wrong to me

Answer (score 0):

Should a customer have a problem [or *Whenever the customer has a problem*, if you prefer], I, as a customer representative, am always ready to offer assistance.

Comment: I agree with some of your change of my sentence, especially the last part 'am always ready to offer assistance'. 'Help' is less formal and usually between friends while 'assistance' is more for a customer representative. However, I notice you made a typo- a customer have a problem. I am not pretty sure if you missed a 's' and just carelessly typed 'have' instead of 'has'. Most importantly, I want explanation.

Comment: @Alan: My apologies. I didn't type it: I copied over your (first and only) complete sample sentence and changed it around. F***ing computers ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I write ' Customers are the assets of our company.' or 'Customer is the asset of our company.'; 'Customers and I should always be satisfied with each other.' or' 'Customer and I should always be satisfied with each other.'?

Comment: Customers are the most important asset our company has. Their satisfaction is our main objective.

Comment: Oh sorry. I just made them up. I don't intend to give the above meaning. My question is only about whether we should have the 's' with 'customer'.

Comment: Assume that the 2 sentences are correct in meaning.

Comment: Note that it should be either "should a customer _have_ a problem" or "Whenever a customer _has_ a problem"

Comment: @Eldroß: Absolutely. I'm kind of drunk right now. Thanks.